# Thunderbird Filter on Subject contains

Tags: thunderbird

I am trying to create an email filter when the Subject contains "Lejeune" and have the email deleted but the message is staying in my Inbox. I have "Match any of the following" selected along with Subject and contains with Lejeune typed into the subject line. I checked "Match all messages" instead of "Match any of the following" and then all messages from my Inbox went into the trash folder.
I have been successful with all of the other filters using "From" instead of "Subject" but the sender throws so many different variations of Lejeune spelling by adding spaces throughout the name.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: This is confusing, if you know the sender then why use the subject. All filters/ rules fine for me.

Comment: It might be better to get the email host to mark these senders as spam. E.G., in GMail, click on the file and create a filter. Also, mark it spam in GMail, so they can remove sender.

Comment: Thank you and I will mark the emails as spam in GMail. The sender's name and address is always changing which is why I was trying to solve the issue in Thunderbird with the Subject. Going directly to GMail does sound like a better idea.